# Why does JS array not include a peek() function?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript arrays include functions that make it handle like a stack out of the box.  Refer to `push(...)` and `pop()`.  If the spec/developers of the language went to the trouble to make arrays stack-like in this way with push/pop functions, why was `peek()` omitted (forcing us instead to always need to index the final element of the array, e.g. `arr[arr.length-1]`)?

I realize that this may be a subjective matter, but I was hoping someone knew something about decisions made/published regarding the language spec that my Google Fu was too weak to unearth.

Comment: @JackBashford Isn't that a tautology? The language was designed that way because that's what the designers wanted?

Comment: JavaScript's core is really lean and tends to steer away from adding frills or luxuries, focusing instead on the pure essentials. If you want better tools, [NPM](http://npmjs.com) has you covered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the line somewhere to be simple.  Furthermore there are several ways to handle peeking an empty array (return null, return undefined, or throw).

> forcing us instead to always need to index the final element of the array

This is not really true, as you can prototype the array if you want, or write a wrapper function.  In the following example, **the wrapper function is actually 1 character less than the native API you desire**.  `peek(a)` vs `a.peek()`.

```js
function peek_or_null(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return array[array.length - 1];
}

function peek(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('out of bounds');
  }
  return array[array.length - 1];
}

Array.prototype.peek = function() {
  if (this.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('out of bounds');
  }
  return this[this.length - 1];
}

const a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a.peek());
console.log(peek(a));
console.log(peek_or_null(a));
```

Answer (score -2):

While the names suggest stacks, that's not really a common use of arrays. `push()` is used all the time when constructing arrays sequentially, having nothing to do with stacks. I don't think `pop()` is used nearly as much, but it's useful as a built-in because it combines multiple operations (fetching and removing); arrays are much more often processed in order without removal, than by popping elements off the end.

`peek()` would be used even less, and I suppose the designers just felt that it wasn't useful enough to make a built-in. As you noted, the code to do it by hand is pretty simple.

A built-in replacement for `arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)]` would almost certainly get far more use than `peek()`, but we don't have that, either.